# How to add temporal variables to first-order logic formulas?

Tags: nlp, prolog, first-order-logic

I've written an English parser in Prolog that uses first-order logic .

I now want to extend  this parser so that it's
able to tell whether a sentence is in the past, present or future.

In other words, I want my English grammar parser to be able to parse a sentence into a first-order logic formula that contains tense/temporal variables

For example :

The sentence `Bill slept.` should  be parsed as `some(T,and(before(T,now),sleep(bill,T))).`

And ambigue  example sentences like `Every mother loves a child.` should still have several possible parsings :

`- some(T,and(eq(T,now), all(X,imp(mother(X),some(Y,and(child(Y),loves(X,Y))))))).`
`- some(T,and(eq(T,now), some(X,and(child(X),all(Y,imp(mother(Y),loves(Y,X))))))).`

However, currently I don't really know how to approach the extension of the first-order logic-formulas with the needed temporal variables.

Therefore my question is if anyone here knows and could point me towards any resources  regarding the extension of first-order logic formulas with temportal variables, or kows about any parsers written in Prolog that can handle tense?

Here is my grammar and parts of the lexicon that are relevant for the example sentences:

**Grammar**

```
/*========================================================================
   Texts
========================================================================*/

t([sem:T])--> 
   s([coord:no,sem:S]),
   {combine(t:T,[s:S])}.

t([sem:T])--> 
   s([coord:yes,sem:S]),
   {combine(t:T,[s:S])}.

t([sem:T])--> 
   q([sem:Q]),
   {combine(t:T,[q:Q])}.


/*========================================================================
   Sentences
========================================================================*/

s([coord:no,sem:Sem])--> 
   np([coord:_,num:Num,gap:[],sem:NP]), 
   vp([coord:_,inf:fin,num:Num,gap:[],sem:VP]), 
   {combine(s:Sem,[np:NP,vp:VP])}.

s([coord:yes,sem:Sem])--> 
   s([coord:ant,sem:S1]), 
   s([coord:con,sem:S2]), 
   {combine(s:Sem,[s:S1,s:S2])}.

s([coord:yes,sem:Sem])--> 
   s([coord:either,sem:S1]), 
   s([coord:or,sem:S2]), 
   {combine(s:Sem,[s:S1,s:S2])}.

s([coord:ant,sem:Sem])--> 
   [if], 
   s([coord:no,sem:S]),
   {combine(s:Sem,[if:S])}.

s([coord:either,sem:Sem])--> 
   [either], 
   s([coord:no,sem:S]),
   {combine(s:Sem,[either:S])}.

s([coord:con,sem:Sem])--> 
   [then], 
   s([coord:no,sem:S]),
   {combine(s:Sem,[then:S])}.

s([coord:con,sem:Sem])-->
   s([coord:no,sem:S]),
   {combine(s:Sem,[then:S])}.

s([coord:or,sem:Sem])-->
   [or], 
   s([coord:no,sem:S]),
   {combine(s:Sem,[or:S])}.

sinv([gap:G,sem:S])-->
   av([inf:fin,num:Num,sem:Sem]),
   np([coord:_,num:Num,gap:[],sem:NP]),
   vp([coord:_,inf:inf,num:Num,gap:G,sem:VP]), 
   {combine(sinv:S,[av:Sem,np:NP,vp:VP])}.


/*========================================================================
   Questions
========================================================================*/

q([sem:Sem])--> 
   whnp([num:Num,sem:NP]), 
   vp([coord:_,inf:fin,num:Num,gap:[],sem:VP]), 
   {combine(q:Sem,[whnp:NP,vp:VP])}.

q([sem:Sem])--> 
   whnp([num:_,sem:NP]), 
   sinv([gap:[np:NP],sem:S]),
   {combine(q:Sem,[sinv:S])}.


/*========================================================================
   Noun Phrases
========================================================================*/

np([coord:no,num:sg,gap:[np:NP],sem:NP])--> [].

np([coord:yes,num:pl,gap:[],sem:NP])--> 
   np([coord:no,num:sg,gap:[],sem:NP1]), 
   coord([type:conj,sem:C]), 
   np([coord:_,num:_,gap:[],sem:NP2]), 
   {combine(np:NP,[np:NP1,coord:C,np:NP2])}.

np([coord:yes,num:sg,gap:[],sem:NP])--> 
   np([coord:no,num:sg,gap:[],sem:NP1]), 
   coord([type:disj,sem:C]), 
   np([coord:_,num:sg,gap:[],sem:NP2]), 
   {combine(np:NP,[np:NP1,coord:C,np:NP2])}.

np([coord:no,num:sg,gap:[],sem:NP])--> 
   det([mood:decl,type:_,sem:Det]), 
   n([coord:_,sem:N]), 
   {combine(np:NP,[det:Det,n:N])}.

np([coord:no,num:sg,gap:[],sem:NP])--> 
   pn([sem:PN]), 
   {combine(np:NP,[pn:PN])}.

np([coord:no,num:sg,gap:[],sem:NP])--> 
   qnp([mood:decl,sem:QNP]), 
   {combine(np:NP,[qnp:QNP])}.


/*========================================================================
   WH Noun Phrases
========================================================================*/

whnp([num:sg,sem:NP])--> 
   qnp([mood:int,sem:QNP]), 
   {combine(whnp:NP,[qnp:QNP])}.

whnp([num:sg,sem:NP])--> 
   det([mood:int,type:_,sem:Det]), 
   n([coord:_,sem:N]), 
   {combine(whnp:NP,[det:Det,n:N])}.


/*========================================================================
   Nouns
========================================================================*/

n([coord:yes,sem:N])--> 
   n([coord:no,sem:N1]), 
   coord([type:_,sem:C]),  
   n([coord:_,sem:N2]),
   {combine(n:N,[n:N1,coord:C,n:N2])}.

n([coord:C,sem:Sem])--> 
   adj([sem:A]), 
   n([coord:C,sem:N]), 
   {combine(n:Sem,[adj:A,n:N])}.

n([coord:no,sem:N])--> 
   noun([sem:Noun]),
   {combine(n:N,[noun:Noun])}.

n([coord:no,sem:Sem])--> 
   noun([sem:N]), 
   nmod([sem:PP]),
   {combine(n:Sem,[noun:N,nmod:PP])}. 

nmod([sem:N])--> 
   pp([sem:PP]),
   {combine(nmod:N,[pp:PP])}.

nmod([sem:N])--> 
   rc([sem:RC]),
   {combine(nmod:N,[rc:RC])}.

nmod([sem:Sem])--> 
   pp([sem:PP]), 
   nmod([sem:NMod]),
   {combine(nmod:Sem,[pp:PP,nmod:NMod])}.


/*========================================================================
   Verb Phrases
========================================================================*/

vp([coord:yes,inf:Inf,num:Num,gap:[],sem:VP])--> 
   vp([coord:no,inf:Inf,num:Num,gap:[],sem:VP1]), 
   coord([type:_,sem:C]), 
   vp([coord:_,inf:Inf,num:Num,gap:[],sem:VP2]),
   {combine(vp:VP,[vp:VP1,coord:C,vp:VP2])}.

vp([coord:no,inf:Inf,num:Num,gap:[],sem:VP])--> 
   av([inf:Inf,num:Num,sem:Mod]), 
   vp([coord:_,inf:inf,num:Num,gap:[],sem:V2]), 
   {combine(vp:VP,[av:Mod,vp:V2])}.

vp([coord:no,inf:Inf,num:Num,gap:[],sem:VP])--> 
   cop([inf:Inf,num:Num,sem:Cop]), 
   np([coord:_,num:_,gap:[],sem:NP]), 
   {combine(vp:VP,[cop:Cop,np:NP])}.

vp([coord:no,inf:Inf,num:Num,gap:[],sem:VP])--> 
   iv([inf:Inf,num:Num,sem:IV]), 
   {combine(vp:VP,[iv:IV])}.

vp([coord:no,inf:I,num:Num,gap:G,sem:VP])-->   
   tv([inf:I,num:Num,sem:TV]), 
   np([coord:_,num:_,gap:G,sem:NP]), 
   {combine(vp:VP,[tv:TV,np:NP])}.


/*========================================================================
   Prepositional Phrases
========================================================================*/

pp([sem:PP])--> 
   prep([sem:Prep]), 
   np([coord:_,num:_,gap:[],sem:NP]), 
   {combine(pp:PP,[prep:Prep,np:NP])}.


/*========================================================================
   Relative Clauses
========================================================================*/

rc([sem:RC])--> 
   relpro([sem:RP]), 
   vp([coord:_,inf:fin,num:sg,gap:[],sem:VP]), 
   {combine(rc:RC,[relpro:RP,vp:VP])}.


/*========================================================================
   Lexical Rules
========================================================================*/

%intransitive_Verbs

iv([inf:Inf,num:Num,sem:Sem])--> 
   {lexEntry(iv,[symbol:Sym,syntax:Word,inf:Inf,num:Num])},
   Word,
   {semLex(iv,[symbol:Sym,sem:Sem])}.
   
%transitive_Verbs

tv([inf:Inf,num:Num,sem:Sem])--> 
   {lexEntry(tv,[symbol:Sym,syntax:Word,inf:Inf,num:Num])},
   Word,
   {semLex(tv,[symbol:Sym,sem:Sem])}.
   
%Copulas

cop([inf:Inf,num:Num,sem:Sem])--> 
   {lexEntry(cop,[pol:Pol,syntax:Word,inf:Inf,num:Num])},
   Word,
   {semLex(cop,[pol:Pol,sem:Sem])}.
   
%Determiners

det([mood:M,type:Type,sem:Det])--> 
   {lexEntry(det,[syntax:Word,mood:M,type:Type])},
   Word,
   {semLex(det,[type:Type,sem:Det])}. 
   
%Proper_nouns

pn([sem:Sem])--> 
   {lexEntry(pn,[symbol:Sym,syntax:Word])},
   Word,  
   {semLex(pn,[symbol:Sym,sem:Sem])}.
   
%relative_Pronouns

relpro([sem:Sem])--> 
   {lexEntry(relpro,[syntax:Word])},
   Word,
   {semLex(relpro,[sem:Sem])}.
   
%Prepositions

prep([sem:Sem])--> 
   {lexEntry(prep,[symbol:Sym,syntax:Word])},
   Word,
   {semLex(prep,[symbol:Sym,sem:Sem])}.
   
%Adjectives

adj([sem:Sem])--> 
   {lexEntry(adj,[symbol:Sym,syntax:Word])},
   Word,
   {semLex(adj,[symbol:Sym,sem:Sem])}.

%Adverbs

av([inf:Inf,num:Num,sem:Sem])--> 
   {lexEntry(av,[syntax:Word,inf:Inf,num:Num,pol:Pol])},
   Word,
   {semLex(av,[pol:Pol,sem:Sem])}.
   
%Coordinators

coord([type:Type,sem:Sem])--> 
   {lexEntry(coord,[syntax:Word,type:Type])},
   Word, 
   {semLex(coord,[type:Type,sem:Sem])}.
   
%Quantified_Noun_Phrases

qnp([mood:M,sem:NP])--> 
   {lexEntry(qnp,[symbol:Symbol,syntax:Word,mood:M,type:Type])},
   Word,
   {semLex(qnp,[type:Type,symbol:Symbol,sem:NP])}.
   
%Nouns

noun([sem:Sem])--> 
   {lexEntry(noun,[symbol:Sym,syntax:Word])},
   Word,
   {semLex(noun,[symbol:Sym,sem:Sem])}.
```

**Lexicon**

```
%Determiners

lexEntry(det,[syntax:[every],mood:decl,type:uni]).
lexEntry(det,[syntax:[a],mood:decl,type:indef]).

%(Proper)Nouns

lexEntry(pn,[symbol:bill,syntax:[bill]]).

lexEntry(noun,[symbol:mother,syntax:[mother]]).
lexEntry(noun,[symbol:child,syntax:[child]]).

%Verbs

lexEntry(iv,[symbol:sleep,syntax:[sleep],inf:inf,num:sg]).
lexEntry(iv,[symbol:sleep,syntax:[sleeps],inf:fin,num:sg]).
lexEntry(iv,[symbol:sleep,syntax:[sleep],inf:fin,num:pl]).

lexEntry(tv,[symbol:love,syntax:[love],inf:inf,num:sg]).
lexEntry(tv,[symbol:love,syntax:[loves],inf:fin,num:sg]).
lexEntry(tv,[symbol:love,syntax:[love],inf:fin,num:pl]).
```

Comment: Please post the parts of your grammar that allow you to parse the sentence `Bill sleeps.`. Then we can show you how to extend it. It makes no sense to try to answer your question if we need to reconstruct all that you have done based purely on guessing.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie: I've added my grammar and relevant parts of the lexicon.

Comment: Nice attempt to overcome a difficult problem!

Comment: @PrologGraph Thanks for posting code, but this now contains a lot of stuff that appears unrelated to parsing something as simple as `Bill sleeps.` but is also missing at least a definition for `semLex/2`.